# plotting the minimum and maximum value

Tags: r

I'm trying to plot the **average amount of time people wait in the queue** with various numbers of servers(N), for example. (min N: 7, max N: 20)

For y-axis, I'm using this formula: y=(82)/(14N*(14N-82))

I'm new to R and this is my first time plotting with formula by inserting min-max values, so I'm not sure if this is the right code but in this case, what should I put for x?

`plot((82)/(14N(14N-82)), x, xlim=range(7:20))`

Comment: Try `plot(7:20, (82/(14 * (7:20) * (14 * (7:20) - 82))))`

Answer (score 0):

```r
N <- seq(7,20)
plot(N, (82)/(14*N*(14*N-82)))
```

[image: plot of just points]

Or with points and lines,

```r
plot(N, (82)/(14*N*(14*N-82)), type="b")
```

[image: points and lines]

Alternatively, using `curve`, we can plot fractional servers. This might be illogical in my assumption that it must be integral, but it's another method.

```r
plot(curve((82)/(14*N*(14*N-82)), xname="N", from=7, to=20))
```

[image: plot from the curve function]

Answer (score 0):

A solution using ggplot2 could look like the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tibble(N = 7:20) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = N, y = 82/(14*N*(14*N-82)))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Adding `+ geom_line()` to the final line above leads to:

[image]